# How to replace www in a website with other words like my, m etc.?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have seen many websites, which don't have www in their URL, they just magically redirect [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to my.example.com.

I am trying to figure it out who it is done, please guide me

Comment: Its a simple mapping. You have to provide the ip in case someone does not enter "www".
https://computer.howstuffworks.com/internet/basics/question180.htm#:~:text=In%20the%20case%20of%20Web,links%20on%20the%20next%20page.

Comment: Why you want to do this with html/css? These are not the right tools to do this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with a "website", but with name resolution in the internet and defining a host inside your http server for that host name you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

As for my.example.com,this is something related to subdomains, from your hosting you can create subdomain for example my.example.com, and you can upload files to the folder assigned to that subdomain.
for www and non www it can be set from hosting also and from [.htaccess](https://www.sitepoint.com/htaccess-for-all/) file.
https://www.keycdn.com/support/popular-htaccess-examples

For example if you add this to .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

you can make redirection

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the prefix www with subdomains. What you want is to add the subdomain 'my' to the domain name 'example.com'

Comment: This only makes sense if one uses a web space hosting provider and their terminology. This is not actually true in a technical sense.